# Nested terms aggregation that aggregate over siblings

Tags: elasticsearch

Not quite sure how to form this question so I'll jump into an example. Assuming I have the following documents:

```
{
    elements: [
        {name: 'foo'},
        {name: 'bar'},
        {name: 'baz'}
    ]
},
{
    elements: [
        {name: 'foo'},
        {name: 'baz'}
    ]  
}
```

Where `elements` contain nested documents. I want to be able to aggregate over every `name` and get counts for how many times a sibling appears with that element.

I.e.

```
{
    foo: {
        bar: 1,
        baz: 2
    },
    bar: {
        foo: 1,
        baz: 1
    },
    baz: {
        foo: 2,
        bar: 1
    }
}
```

Is there a neat way to do this using elasticsearch aggregations? My primitive understanding of aggregations in ES had me doing something like:

```
"aggs": {
    "elements": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "elements"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "names": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "elements.name",
                    "size": 20
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "more_elements": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "elements.name",
                            "size": 20
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives completely incorrect results. I end up getting something like:

```
{
    foo: {
        doc_count: 2, 
        foo: 2
    },
    bar: {
        doc_count: 1, 
        foo: 1
    },
    baz: {
        doc_count: 2, 
        foo: 2
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! I am currently using ES 5.4 if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find a way to do it in one step.
I'll separate it to two steps:

Step 1: find all elements.names:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "elements": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "elements"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "elements.name",
            "size": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2: for each element.name do:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "bool_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "elements.name": "NAME_HERE"
            }
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "names": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "elements.name",
              "size": 20
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pay attention that I'm not using nested aggregation here - the [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) would filter every (full) document that contains the current name. Than I'm just getting the appearance number of every sibling (and also the current name - but it can be removed as well).